# Why was my reputation not restored after my edit was restored?

Tags: support, reputation

I recently made an edit to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/389438/how-to-play-online-after-being-banned-in-battlefield-1942), which was subsequently reverted by the post owner. However, it was later rolled back again by a moderator to my edit:

[image: Screenshot of the edit history for the question.]

When I made the edit, I was awarded a simple 2 reputation points:

[image: Screenshot of the reputation awarded for the edit.]

And, when the post was rolled back by the owner, I lost those 2 reputation points:

[image: Screenshot of the reversion message.]

But, when the moderator rolled the post back to my edit, the reputation was not re-awarded. While this doesn't bother me, it does make me curious as to why the reputation would be awarded, and taken away, but not awarded back. Is this a bug, or by design? If it's by design, why?

<sub>***Note**: I'll add the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag if this is determined to be a bug.*</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your edit was not restored, it was rejected by the question owner. After a suggested edit is approved, it can still be rejected by the owner or a moderator, which then ends the review for good. A rollback to a previous edit does not then accept the suggested edit again, it simply restores a post's previous state.

Comment: Sounds fair enough, just made me really curious lol